# How to get the FolderID from Google Drive folders using Chilkat DLL

Tags: vb.net, winforms, google-drive-api, chilkat

Im using the ChilKat to develop a tool using VB.NET, that performs a single file upload to my google drive account.
**Im able to get the folderID within a root folder**, but im struggling to get the folderID if there is a path of folders.

At this moment the **argument FolderPath is not being used** (i will, when i uncover how to properly get the FolderID). For now, **i can get the "Nova" folder id**, but none of the other folders within the following tree:

[image]

Is there an easier way to get the folderID from GoogleDrive?
I would also like to create the path of folders on Google Drive, in case they dont exist.

I never worked with JSON or HTTP requests, so im kind of lost here.
Any help would be mostly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

```
Private Function FolderID(ByVal FolderPath As String) As String

    Dim rest As New Chilkat.Rest

    '  Connect using TLS.
    Dim success As Boolean = rest.Connect("www.googleapis.com", 443, True, True)

    '  Provide the authentication credentials (i.e. the access token)
    Dim gAuth As New Chilkat.AuthGoogle
    gAuth.AccessToken = M_AccessToken
    rest.SetAuthGoogle(gAuth)

    Dim json As New Chilkat.JsonObject
    json.EmitCompact = False

    '  Get the folder Testes folder that is in the Google Drive root.
    rest.AddQueryParam("q", "'root' in parents and name='Testes'")
    Dim jsonResponse As String = rest.FullRequestNoBody("GET", "/drive/v3/files")
    If Not rest.LastMethodSuccess Then
        Return rest.LastErrorText
        Exit Function
    End If

    json.Load(jsonResponse)

    rest.ClearAllQueryParams()

    '  Now that we know the ID for the Testes directory, get the id for the folder Nova having Testes as the parent.
    Dim sbQuery As New Chilkat.StringBuilder
    sbQuery.Append("name = 'nova' and '")
    sbQuery.Append(json.StringOf("files[0].id"))
    sbQuery.Append("' in parents")

    rest.AddQueryParamSb("q", sbQuery)

    jsonResponse = rest.FullRequestNoBody("GET", "/drive/v3/files")
    If Not rest.LastMethodSuccess Then
        Return (rest.LastErrorText)
        Exit Function
    End If

    json.Load(jsonResponse)

    Return json.StringOf("files[0].id")

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed a way by performing iterative requests.
Don't know if this is the correct way, but it works...

Here's the code, now using the FolderPath with format /folder1/folder2/folderN

```
Private Function GetFolderID(ByVal FolderPath As String) As String

    Dim Rest As New Chilkat.Rest

    ' Connect to Google APIs server
    Dim Connected As Boolean = Rest.Connect("www.googleapis.com", 443, True, True)
    If Not Connected Then
        Return "Error attempting to connect: " & Rest.ConnectFailReason
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Provide the Access token
    Dim GAuth As New Chilkat.AuthGoogle
    GAuth.AccessToken = M_AccessToken
    Rest.SetAuthGoogle(GAuth)

    ' Instance to JSON object
    Dim JSON As New Chilkat.JsonObject
    JSON.EmitCompact = False

    ' Parse the provided path and split to array
    Dim ParseFolder As String = Strings.Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 1)
    Dim Folders As String() = Split(ParseFolder, "/")

    '  Get the root folder that is in the Google Drive folders structure
    Rest.AddQueryParam("q", "'root' in parents and name='" & Folders(0) & "'")
    Dim Response As String = Rest.FullRequestNoBody("GET", "/drive/v3/files")
    If Not Rest.LastMethodSuccess Then
        Return Rest.LastErrorText
        Exit Function
    End If
    JSON.Load(Response)

    'Iterate on the folders to get the last folder's id
    Rest.ClearAllQueryParams()
    For i = 1 To Folders.Length - 1
        Dim sbQuery As New Chilkat.StringBuilder

        sbQuery.Append("name = '" & Folders(i) & "' and '")
        sbQuery.Append(JSON.StringOf("files[0].id"))
        sbQuery.Append("' in parents")

        Rest.AddQueryParamSb("q", sbQuery)

        Response = Rest.FullRequestNoBody("GET", "/drive/v3/files")

        If Not Rest.LastMethodSuccess Then
            Return Rest.LastErrorText
            Exit Function
        End If

        JSON.Load(Response)
    Next

    ' Get the folder id
    Return JSON.StringOf("files[0].id")

End Function
```